Outdoor faucet too low
This exterior faucet is too low to connect a hose.

It's very old and doesn't leak but the interior valve started leaking after I turned it on/off a few times:

The interior space is very tight but I hope I'll be able to replace the interior valve (any advice welcome on how to do it - I might call a specialist for this)
But the bigger question is should I replace the exterior faucet and with what?  I usually use something like this:
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Homewerks-Worldwide-1-2-in-x-12-in-Brass-Anti-Siphon-Frost-Free-Sillcock-Valve-with-Push-Fit-Connections-P140-8-12x12/203518399
But it's still very low and almost impossible to attach a hose.
Can the faucet face upwards or sideways?  Are there other faucets on the market can help (perhaps like the old one shown here: Exterior faucet - freeze hazard?)?
Or should I dig a hole and create a buried box that contains the faucet and the whole hose?

Most likely the interior valve just needs (easy) the packing nut tightened slightly or {marginally more difficult} repacking, rather than replacement, if the corrosion is where it's leaking. As for outside, do you own a shovel or a trowel?

Regarding the lowness of the faucet, if removing the stuff underneath the faucet won't help, try one or more "gooseneck hose couplings" to wrap the final hose connection up so you can get a hose on the end.

Your idea of digging a recess underneath seems simplest... as long as there is no chance of the valve ever being under water after heavy rain. In the admittedly unlikely event of the valve being submerged while open, and a loss of water pressure, ground water could siphon into potable water.
